# Get Google Spreadsheet Data

Tags: sockets, google-sheets

Is there a way to view data on a google spreadsheet via a socket? If so, how may I do so?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/

version 1.0 has numerous libraries in various programming languages including php and python
version 2.0 and 3.0 answer only to java and .NET

hope this helps

Comment: there is also another api for the docs and mentioned by @stewe but the the specific one for the data inside spreadsheets is the one i mentioned

Comment: Would there be a way to socket-connect to a sheet via mIRC?